# How to set up a prompt after the click of a button?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a prompt that will show up after a click of a button and the changes are applied.

However, I really couldn't make it work. I've been trying to finish this tool for some hours now and this is the last thing I need for it to be completed.

Here's the code I have so far:

```js
const mapper01 = new Map();
mapper01.set("3d", "4th");
mapper01.set("149", "158, 159");
mapper01.set("150", "160");
mapper01.set("151", "161");
mapper01.set("152", "162");
mapper01.set("153", "163");
mapper01.set("154", "164");
mapper01.set("155", "165");
mapper01.set("156", "166");
mapper01.set("157", "167");
mapper01.set("158", "168");

function crimesAgainstgovernmental() {
  const elm = document.getElementById("textarea3");
  if (elm) {
    elm.value = elm.value
      .replaceAll(
        /\b\d+(?:([A-Z])\1?|d|th|st|nd)?(-[A-Z\d]+)?\b/g,
        m => mapper01.has(m) ? mapper01.get(m) : m
      );
  }
}

document.getElementById("promptchanges").onclick = function() {
  if (confirm('Changes applied!')) {
    crimesAgainstgovernmental();
  } else {
  }
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control" id="textarea3" spellcheck="true" rows="4">157, 158. Onclick of button there should be a prompt notifying that changes are applied.</textarea>

<button class="btn btn-sm upbtn ml-2 mt-2" id="promptchanges" onclick="crimesAgainstgovernmental();"><b>Button</b></button>
```

I apologize if this question is too simple yet I can't do. But I'm still trying to learn more about coding but I just need to finish this quick tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `}` for your function invoked on `onclick`

```js
const mapper01 = new Map();
mapper01.set("3d", "4th");
mapper01.set("149", "158, 159");
mapper01.set("150", "160");
mapper01.set("151", "161");
mapper01.set("152", "162");
mapper01.set("153", "163");
mapper01.set("154", "164");
mapper01.set("155", "165");
mapper01.set("156", "166");
mapper01.set("157", "167");
mapper01.set("158", "168");

function crimesAgainstgovernmental() {
  const elm = document.getElementById("textarea3");
  if (elm) {
    elm.value = elm.value
      .replaceAll(/\b\d+(?:([A-Z])\1?|d|th|st|nd)?(-[A-Z\d]+)?\b/g,m => mapper01.has(m) ? mapper01.get(m) : m);
  }
}

document.getElementById("promptchanges").onclick = function() {
  if (confirm('Changes applied!')) {
    crimesAgainstgovernmental();
  } else {
  }
  }/*<-- This is the one*/
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control" id="textarea3" spellcheck="true" rows="4">157, 158. Onclick of button there should be a prompt notifying that changes are applied.</textarea>

<button class="btn btn-sm upbtn ml-2 mt-2" id="promptchanges" onclick="crimesAgainstgovernmental();"><b>Button</b></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

seems like you were just missing a closing }

```js
const mapper01 = new Map();
mapper01.set("3d", "4th");
mapper01.set("149", "158, 159");
mapper01.set("150", "160");
mapper01.set("151", "161");
mapper01.set("152", "162");
mapper01.set("153", "163");
mapper01.set("154", "164");
mapper01.set("155", "165");
mapper01.set("156", "166");
mapper01.set("157", "167");
mapper01.set("158", "168");

function crimesAgainstgovernmental() {
  const elm = document.getElementById("textarea3");
  if (elm) {
    elm.value = elm.value
      .replaceAll(
        /\b\d+(?:([A-Z])\1?|d|th|st|nd)?(-[A-Z\d]+)?\b/g,
        m => mapper01.has(m) ? mapper01.get(m) : m
      );
  }
}

document.getElementById("promptchanges").onclick = function() {
  if (confirm('Changes applied!')) {
    crimesAgainstgovernmental();
  } else {
  }
  
  }
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control" id="textarea3" spellcheck="true" rows="4">157, 158. Onclick of button there should be a prompt notifying that changes are applied.</textarea>

<button class="btn btn-sm upbtn ml-2 mt-2" id="promptchanges" onclick="crimesAgainstgovernmental();"><b>Button</b></button>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out sir! It seems I just forgot that one. hehe!